# Specify install path for Ender

Tags: javascript, npm, ender

When using [Ender](http://ender.no.de/) I would like to specify a directory where packages should be installed.

The only way to make this work seems to be to `cd directory; ender build package`, but I might be wrong?

Idealy I would have a package.json file, where I can specify a path where dependencies should be placed.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you can append `--output path/to/ender` to specify the path. For other operations such as  add/remove/list it is `--use`. For example:

```
ender build qwery bean bonzo --output public/scripts/ender
```

That would create the ender.js and ender.min.js files under public/scripts.

There is discussion on making this better, e.g., as you mentioned regarding putting the path in package.json. You can read about that on the [github issue](https://github.com/ender-js/Ender/issues/131).

In the mean time, if you use gruntjs, [there is a plugin](https://github.com/endium/grunt-ender) that can handle this as well (disclaimer: I wrote the plugin).